# Why RewriteRule isn't working in this case?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is my `.htaccess`.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\/images\/(.*)\.png$ /images/%1.jpg
```

Now what I want to do is that 
`http://blabla1001.net46.net/images/pegion.png`
should be redirected to 
`http://blabla1001.net46.net/images/pegion.jpg`
but this does not happen instead I am getting redirected to `404.php`.

Why is this happening?

Here is my directory structure:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%1` is actually back-reference for value captured in `RewriteCond`, use `$1`:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(images/.+?)\.png$ /$1.jpg [NE,L,NC,R=302]
```